# Short directories in vim tabs like a/b/c/Filename.txt

Tags: vim

there is **guitablabel** option in vim which allows one to modify tab title. But I would like to change it to some macro perhaps, which would give me titles like:

```
a/b/c/Filename.txt
```

where directories are replaced with single characters. Or anything similar would also work. Do you have any snippets or plugin tips? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like

`:set guitablabel=%{substitute(expand('%:p'),'/\\zs\\(.\\)[^/]*\\ze/','\\1','g')}`

This sets the `:help guitablabel` option to display the file /path/to/file.txt as /p/t/file.txt. It uses expression evaluation `%{ }` (documented under `:help statusline`) to evaluate the substitution (`:help substitute()`) with a pattern.

Comment: If I'm reading the help correctly it looks like the 'guitablabel' option uses the same format as the 'statusline' option so this may work exactly as is just by setting the correct option.